# importing a project into a svn repository question

Tags: svn, netbeans, backup

im using netbeans for svn.

i open a project in netbeans and then i import it to a svn repo.

it seems that although im only importing the project folder, svn creates .svn folders in all folders within this project folder.

why is that? i thought that i was only creating .svn folders to checked out projects, not imported ones?

now this folder acts very weird, when i open this folder as a project in netbeans, netbeans treats it like a svn folder some way.

is this normal? cause i want this one to not be under SVN.

Comment: Do you mean that when you import folder "A", it gets the .svn directory and all of subdirs of "A" get the .svn directory too?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i meant=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like importing the project also turned it into a working copy.

Comment: yes...weird...cause i dont want to make it a working copy..but have it original...guess i have to COPY first THEN import :)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide svn exclusions for **/.svn/ in Java build path for that project. Netbeans will ignore these folders.